# Passing current user parameters into nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-5, parameter-passing, nested-attributes

I am trying to pass through a devise user id from my Agent model (current_agent.id) into my Nested AgentActivity model whenever I update the parameters on my Submission model. How would I go about achieving this?

Currently my code on Submission controller (doesn't throw an error but doesn't do anything):

```
@submission.agent_activities.first.agent_id = current_agent.id

respond_to do |format|
  if @submission.update(submission_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @submission, notice: 'Submission was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @submission }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @submission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're just assigning agent_id, but don't saving it. Should be:

```
@submission.agent_activities.first.update(agent_id: current_agent.id)
```

And this line should go after `if @submission.update(submission_params)`

Comment: @WernerAdewole, could you please accept an answer if it works for you